# Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

Tags: java, netbeans

When i want to run a project in NetBeans, it just displays this message:

> "Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M".

What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=$HOME/tmp"
```

in your bash shell.

Alternatively, if you're using Windows, you may have encounter `_JAVA_OPTIONS` variables for both User&System Environment variables. If so, delete each of them, and recall netbeans.

Comment: Excuse me, i didnt understand. How can i do that?How i use it? Where?

Comment: @nirvana just right click on "My Computer" -> "Properties"->"Advenced System Settings"->"Advenced tab"->"Environment Settings"