# Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javaoptions

Why always show,

> **Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true**

Red colored line when I run every code in NetBeans.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44648599/picked-up-java-options-xmx512m). In other words, check your Linux/Windows environment variables, as mentioned in the link.

Comment: Thank you sir, for letting me know. I figured out that problem occurred because of user and system variables of _JAVA_OPTIONS. It resolved after I deleted that variables.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problem (Linux OS) with

> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true

and it was solved with terminal command

> unset _JAVA_OPTIONS